# SQL UPDATE SUM VALUE NOT NULL

Tags: sql, sql-update, stored-procedures, checksum

```
dataTmp     referencia  nStock
2017-02-18  DC01234567  NULL    
2017-02-18  DC01234567  NULL    
2017-02-18  DC01234567  NULL    
2017-02-19  DC01234567  0   
2017-02-19  DC01234567  0   
2017-02-19  DC01234567  0   
2017-02-20  DC01234567  0
2017-02-20  DC01234567  -450    
2017-02-20  DC01234567  -450    
2017-02-18  RE21341241  NULL    
2017-02-18  RE21341241  NULL    
2017-02-18  RE21341241  NULL    
2017-02-19  RE21341241  1000    
2017-02-19  RE21341241  1000
2017-02-19  RE21341241  1000    
2017-02-20  RE21341241  1000
2017-02-20  RE21341241  -5000   
2017-02-20  RE21341241  -6000
```

Tenho está tabela onde actualizo apartir de uma "Stored Procedures" o valor de hoje em todas as referencias , Soma o Stock em uma tabela onde tem os stocks e poe os resultados Nesta mesma tabela , por exemplo , busca o "sum(stock) from stocks" e coloca no respectivo dia

o problema é que quando não encontra o valor coloca NULL,
o que pretendo é que coloque 0 quando não encontra o sum ... já tentei pesquisar mas estou um pouco perdido

Stored Procedure:

```
UPDATE tabela1 SET nStock=(
SELECT  SUM(stock) as TotalStock
FROM Tabelastock 
INNER JOIN Vis_Armazem ON Tabelastock .Sloc=Vis_Armazem.Sloc 
WHERE Vis_Armazem.mostrar=1 AND Tabelastock.data=(select dateadd(dd,0, cast(getdate() as date))) 
AND Tabelastock.referencia=tabela1 .referencia
group by referencia)
where tabela1.dataTmp=(select dateadd(dd,0, cast(getdate() as date)))
```

Comment: Use `Isnull(sum(stock), 0) as TotalStock`

Comment: olá sim já experimentei , no entanto continua a dar NULL em algumas referencias

Comment: Use na subselect do set então.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de algum tempo de pesquisa aqui está :

```
UPDATE Matrix SET nStock=COALESCE((
SELECT sum(stock) as TotalStock               
FROM stock 
INNER JOIN Vis_Armazem ON stock.Sloc=Vis_Armazem.Sloc 
WHERE Vis_Armazem.mostrar=1 AND stock.data=(select dateadd(dd,0, cast(getdate() as date))) 
AND stock.referencia=Matrix.referencia
group by referencia
),0)
FROM Matrix 
where Matrix.dataTmp=(select dateadd(dd,0, cast(getdate() as date)))
```

"COALESCE" funciona sobre SELECT inteiro e substitui por um valor caso não encontrado , neste caso "0"